# Replacing characters in a string using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, character

I'm supposed to make a program that replaces vowels in a string for numbers, **without using  and using pointers**.

I used the commented printf in each switch statement to debug my program, and the output when the string is: **aeiou**, is:

```
4eiou
3iou
1ou
0u
2
```

and at the end when printing the string it just prints a blank line, when the output should be: **43102**.

I'm doing something wrong that's replacing the complete string, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changes(char* ptr) {

    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        switch(*ptr) {
            case 'a':
                *(ptr)='4';
                //printf("%s\n", ptr);
                break;
            case 'e':
                *(ptr)='3';
                //printf("%s\n", ptr);
                break;
            case 'i':
                *(ptr)='1';
                //printf("%s\n", ptr);
                break;
            case 'o':
                *(ptr)='0';
                //printf("%s\n", ptr);
                break;
            case 'u':
                *(ptr)='2';
                //printf("%s\n", ptr);
                break;
            default: 
            break;
        }
        ptr++;
    }

    //Print the string
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}

int main() {

    char sString[51];
    char *charPtr = NULL;

    charPtr = &sString[0];

    printf("Introduce a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", sString);

    changes(charPtr);
}
```

Comment: Format code as code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incrementing the pointer and printing what it points to using `%s` format specifier of `printf`. Keep a pointer to the beginning of the string and print it. You will see the desired behavior.

```
char *s = ptr;
while(*ptr != 0){

 ..
 printf("%s",s);
}
```

This will print the whole string.(And you can notice the changes that you have made).

Comment: This makes so much sense now! Thank you very much! I was definitely needing another head to help me find my mistake :)